# Angular Material AutoComplete with clear button is getting cleared by Enter

Tags: angular, angular-material

Adding clear button (Section [Input with a clear button](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)) to my [autocomplete component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) results in strange behaviour: hitting enter clears input either it's selected option or not.

To illustrate my issue, I modified stackblitz from originial angular material doc about autocomplete - added clear button behaviour. See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbjb3q?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)

I cannot figure out why this clear button works correctly in case of simple input, but breaks everything in case of autocomplete component, why it's being focused instead of input and 'click' handler is being called.

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `MatFormField` is inside a `form`, the clear button has the `submit` type by default, and it becomes [the default button](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission). Therefore, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in an input element of the form, the button in clicked and the form is submitted. To prevent that, set the attribute `type="button"` on the clear button:

```
<button type="button" mat-button ...>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbjb3q-y7o9la?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html) for a demo.

Comment: Well, now it seems so obvious :) thank you, ConnorsFan!

Comment: It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.

any other solution since this warning? thanks